# How do I display the bottom border of parent instead of top border of child?

Tags: html, css, border-layout

Here is what I have - http://jsfiddle.net/SQApr/

CSS

```
/*
** MainNav is the div containing the navigation information
** This is defining overall size and shape
*/
#mainNav {
    clear: both;

    min-height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;

    position: relative;
}

/*
** Main list padding and style
*/
#mainNav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
}

/*
** Expand nav list for new information
*/
#mainNav ul:hover {height: 240px;}

/*
** Main item size and position
*/
#mainNav li {
    float: left;
    width: 19.805%;
    height: 40px;

    border-left: 1px solid #E8DEA5;     /*******************************************/
    border-right: 1px solid #E8DEA5;    /* Make the border exist for sizing issues */
    border-top: 1px solid #E8DEA5;      /*******************************************/
}

/*
** Main item on hover
*/
#mainNav li:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff; /* White */

    border-left: 1px solid green;
    border-right: 1px solid green;
    border-top: 1px solid green;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

/*
** Main item link formatting
*/
#mainNav li a {
    margin: 0;
    display: block;

    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000; /* Black */
}

/*
** Main div position and bg color on list item hover
*/
#mainNav li:hover .mainDiv {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;

    background-color: #ffffff; /* White */
}

/*
** Any div within mainNav's li must have position relative
*/
#mainNav li div {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/*
** Main div position
*/
#mainNav li .mainDiv {
    width: 1024px; /* Same as #wrapper in styles.css */
    height: 200px;
    left: -9999px;

    border: 1px green solid;
}

#mainNav li .title {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    left: 50px;

    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #0b5a5a; /* Gray blue */

    border-bottom: 2px solid #0b5a5a; /* Gray blue */
}

.navLinks li {
    float: left;
    display: block;

    border: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div style="width:1024px;">
<div id="mainNav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            <div class="mainDiv">
                <span class="title">Welcome to the website!</span>
                <div style="border:red 1px solid;
                            top: 60px;
                            left: 60px;
                            width: 400px;
                            height: 80px;">
                    Here will be a paragraph filled with more information about what the site does
                    and how it will benefit the community and companies. Or anything else you
                    would like to say on every page.
                </div>
                <div style="border:red 1px solid;
                            clear: both;
                            top: -60px;
                            left: 600px;
                            width: 200px;
                            height: 80px;">
                    <ul class="navLinks">
                        <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Third link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>   
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Community</a>
            <div class="mainDiv">
                <span class="title">Community</span>
                <a href="#">Browse People & Companies</a></br>
                <a href="#">Directory</a></br>
                Make Your Voice Heard</br>
                <a href="#">Forums</a>
            </div>   
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Information</a>
            <div class="mainDiv">
                <span class="title">Information</span>
                <a href="#">First link</a></br>
                List within a list
                        First link</a></br>
                        Second link</a></br>
                        Section Title</br>
                        <a href="#">Third link</a>
                </br>
                <a href="#">Third link</a>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Business Opportunities</a>
            <div class="mainDiv">
                <span class="title">Business Opportunities</span>
                <a href="#">First link</a></br>
                <a href="#">Second link</a></br>
                <a href="#">Third link</a>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Support</a>
            <div class="mainDiv">
                <span class="title">Support</span>
                <a href="#">FAQs</a></br>
                <a href="#">Site Map</a></br>
                <a href="#">Third link</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

When ever you roll over the list items to display the hidden div they contain, the top border of the div overlaps the bottom border of the list item. I need to reverse this to make it look like the list item opens up into the div.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any problems understanding the "jsfiddle must be accompanied by code" message? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code

Comment: Yes, I find it completely useless if there is a link provided for people to test... But I'll add code if it will protect me from being down voted.

Comment: By using javascript. AFAIK, with CSS, hovering a parent can affect a child. Hovering a child can't effect a parent however. Hence the JS. just add/remove a particular class with the JS. You can still use css if you do so.

Comment: The goal here is to give people what they need to help you address your issue.  If you post a link with no context, you're not really helping people who might otherwise glance at your work and jump in to help.  You're just adding another barrier when you refuse to post code.  @Fabrício is really just helping you out with his comment.

Comment: I'm starting to see this kind of bypassing behavior on a daily basis. I don't know what is more wrong - the SO system going all the way down by blocking jsfiddle-link only questions or users bypassing it. Seems more like a cause-consequence thing. I'm not really ranting at you, but rather how SO fails to educate users into posting self-contained questions.

Comment: I meant no disrespect to Fabricio and I appreciate all of the comments. Thanks to Chanckjh and Fabricio for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give the div that opens up a `z-index: -1`

like here: http://jsfiddle.net/SQApr/3/

Comment: You forgot to add `z-index: -1` on jsFiddle - correct version [http://jsfiddle.net/SQApr/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/SQApr/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Change `li:hover a` - add white bottom border, make its position relative to add z-index

See: http://jsfiddle.net/SQApr/1/

By the way: I also had to add negative margin to `li:hover .mainDiv`

**Edit:**

Chanckjh version is much simpler than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the z-index property to put the nav over the mainDiv, giving the mainDiv a lower value than the nav.

[z-index at W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)